# A Fragment's height (in a Viewpager) cannot be reduced

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a tablayout with a viewpager that contains four fragments, the first 3 tabs( fragments) works fine. But the last fragment's height cannot be reduced . Its layout contains only an Imageview with fixed size height. but the fragment height is always greater than the imageview. I tried to put the imageview inside a frame layout and linearlayout, trying all height possibilities: match_parent, wrap_content and fixed size height but, it didn't work.
I tried to add maxHeight to the imageview with no luck.
I guessed that the problem may be with the view pager since it may be measuring other fragment's height and stuck with this height, but why other fragments is working fine.So I need your help. Thanks in advance
This is my last fragment layout:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="260dp"
  android:maxHeight="260dp"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:src="@drawable/gs350f"/>
```

And this is the viewpager layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/car_overview_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/high" />


<com.myproject.ui.custom.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/overview_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/car_overview_tabs" />
```

And finally this is NonSwipeableViewPager class:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
      super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
      return false;
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is height of the last image in pixel? Give any background of image for testing purpose...

Comment: @RameshKumar I put a 450*274 image with no change.

Comment: Image height is small can you replace image with large image to check wether it is image fault or not. Change scaletype to fitxy in image view

Comment: @RameshKumar Before I use 450*274 image, I used 1024 image 1024*587 image. I tried fitxy also, the scale changes but the space the imageview occupies still the same.

Comment: change this: 
  android:layout_height="260dp"
  android:maxHeight="260dp" to android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: @RameshKumar unfortunately didn't work also.